# PhpStorm/IDEA inline hints for (HTML) closing tags?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Using GitToolbox I get these inline blame hints:

[image: GTB hints]

It also shows this looking glass thing when I select a closing bracket:
[Large image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk9Qh.png)

This indicates it knows the start tag and has the ability to show inline hints.

Is there any way to show the start tag as an inline hint, even if through a (paid) plugin?

Comment: there are no plugins/options for this; where would you like to have it shown as inline hint? To the right of the closing tag, or?

Comment: @lena Right, where the git blame is also shown. Really just `div.container` or the first 30 or so characters of the block opening tag (i.e. `if($cond1 == true && $verylongcondcutoff...`), to easily see what the starting tag/block open is.

Comment: you can see this info in [breadcrumbs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.2/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#editor_breadcrumbs)... Plus, the start tag is shown in the upper left corner in a tooltip when you are on the closing `>`

Comment: I am aware, but neither of those is what I'm looking for